# Querying the Status of a Service on mac using python

Tags: python, macos

Like Windows32ServiceUtil api in windows how can we check a service is whether running or not by its name in mac os x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to do this via psutil library

```
import psutil
all_processes = [p.as_dict() for p in psutil.process_iter()]
```

gives a dict of all info of processes in os

now we can iterate through the dict for path , exepath, name of process.
and return pid as required.
`for i in all_processes:
            if 'Google Chrome' in i['name']
                return i['pid']`

if it is a python process we can check it through the path of the exe.